# How to manually populate a relational model in Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm still new to Django and DRF. I have 2 models (Policy and Rescue) and Rescue is related to Policy by the Foreign Key policy_id. I have no issue to POST a JSON message and get Policy populated with the request data by CreateView. However, the 2nd model Rescue needs be populated based on some calculations from the JSON data POSTed to the Policy. Rescue cannot be POSTed beforehand. I tried hard but had no clue to do so.

Is this something to do with nested serializer or something else?

I've tried to

Can I try this way: inside the class CreateView:

```
class CreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        ...
        # get a policy object based on 'policy_id' against serializer
        my_policy = Policy.objects.get(policy_id=my_serializer.data['policy_id'])
        ...
        ... # some calculations to work out a rescue id, and will be returned and saved.
        Rescue.objects.create(rescue_id='QD1234', policy=my_policy)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a generic `CreateAPIView` and override the perform_create method.

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    my_policy = serializer.save()
    # you custom calculation for rescue_id
    rescue_obj = Rescue.objects.create(rescue_id='QD1234', policy=my_policy)
```

perform create method is documented here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods

Comment: Thanks, but how could I do some validation of the data for Rescue? We still need an instance for its serializer? I tried to do rescue_obj.is_valid(), but apparently this obj doesn't have this method.

Comment: @Kai that is a completely different question. You should ask another question or modify this one to include what do you want. You should learn a bit how stackoverflow works. Comments are not a good way to provide context to the answer. The question should be clear.

Comment: thanks. I think data population should include validation. It's not an isolated issue.

Comment: @Kai you are welcome. Explicit is better than implicit